# How to return the nearest distinctive times for multiple meetings? [MySQL]

Tags: mysql

I'm going to try and explain this the best I can.

How the process should go:

- Parent logs into parent area. (Parent has `1` or `x` amount of children)
- Area shows the information for their first child (can switch views between each child if has more than 1)
- Parent clicks parents meeting list, then selects a parents meeting.
- Parent meeting starts to load, get all the information for this parents meeting.
- Based on this first meeting loading, we will have the startTime of the meeting.
- On this startTime, will then do another query to database checking for all the meetings which start in range of an hour before or after the already gathered meeting.
- With this I want to determine a slot time for the parents children for all the meetings. However the meeting times have to be the closest they can be and they have to be distinctive.

My idea with this is to just give a suggestion for the parent booking a meeting for all their children, so based on the startTime of their already chosen meeting. It will suggest a slot time for their child they have active in the view. Then search if they have another child which need a time for this meeting. Also search for all the other meetings in a hour range of the startTime and then check if their children need a time for these meetings. Then find the nearest slot time for these based around the selected meeting when they logged into the parent area.

I would just like some advise on how I would start to do this with mysql and returning the best possible times for each child meetings and to workout so that the times don't clash with each child meeting times. (A parent could have twins which will need a individual meeting time for the same lesson).

Here is some information which would be in my database:

```
Parent: [
    id: 1
]
Children: [
    Child1: [
       id: 1
       parent_id: 1
       lesson_id: 86
    ]
    Child1: [
       id: 1
       parent_id: 1
       lesson_id: 87
    ]
    Child2: [
       id: 2
       parent_id: 1
       lesson_id: 88
    ]
    Child3: [
       id: 3
       parent_id: 1
       lesson_id: 87
    ]
]
Meetings: [
    Meeting1: [
        id: 1
        lesson_id: 86
        startTime: 2016-10-07 14:30:00
    ]
    Meeting2: [
        id: 2
        lesson_id: 87
        startTime: 2016-10-07 14:45:00

    ]
    Meeting3: [
        id: 3
        lesson_id: 88
        startTime: 2016-10-07 14:50:00
    ]
]

Meeting_appointments: [
    [
        meeting_id: 1
        type: slot
        startTime: 2016-10-07 14:30:00
        endTime: 2016-10-07 14:40:00
        parent_id: 0
        child_id: 0
    ],
    [
        meeting_id: 1
        type: slot
        startTime: 2016-10-07 14:40:00
        endTime: 2016-10-07 14:50:00
        parent_id: 0
        child_id: 0
    ],
    [
        meeting_id: 2
        type: slot
        startTime: 2016-10-07 14:45:00
        endTime: 2016-10-07 14:55:00
        parent_id: 0
        child_id: 0

    ],
    [
        meeting_id: 2
        type: slot
        startTime: 2016-10-07 14:55:00
        endTime: 2016-10-07 15:25:00
        parent_id: 0
        child_id: 0
    ],
    [
        meeting_id: 3
        type: slot
        startTime: 2016-10-07 14:50:00
        endTime: 2016-10-07 14:55:00
        parent_id: 2
        child_id: 3
    ]
]
```